# Can I use a macro in \halign's preamble?

Tags: align, plain-tex

I'm using Plain TeX and want to be able to abstract away the preamble of an `\halign` so that I can just call it with a number of columns in a macro like `\customalign`, and I want to use a macro to make it more legible. However, this minimal example of using a macro to define the structure of the `\halign`

```
\edef\preamb{## & ## \cr}
\halign{ \preamb
first line & second column \cr
}
```

results in these errors:

```
! Missing # inserted in alignment preamble.
<to be read again> 
                   &
l.3 first line &
                         second column \cr
? 
! Missing # inserted in alignment preamble.
<to be read again> 
                   \cr 
l.3 first line & second column \cr

? 
 )
```

Am I doing something incorrectly, or is this just not possible?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Very nice first question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can: `\span`, when used in the alignment preamble, expands the next token.

```
\def\preamb{## & ## \cr}
\halign{\span\preamb
first line & second column \cr
}

\bye
```

As a rule, tokens before the first `\cr` are not expanded, unless they're preceded by `\span`. A different approach, if the preamble is stored in a single macro is

```
\halign\expandafter{\preamb
first line & second column \cr
}
```

but `\span` is more versatile.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\span` or `\expandafter` to expand macros in the preamble but in either case it forces a slightly unnatural call structure when you use the macro.

An alternative is to define an alternative command (`myhalign` here) that builds in the required preamble. You can avoid pre-scanning the alignment body by using a `\let` to gobble the `{` in the source allowing the preamble starting with an unmatched `\bgroup` to be inserted:

```
\def\myhalign{\afterassignment\xmyhalign\let\tmp=}
\def\xmyhalign{\halign\bgroup\hfil## & ##\hfil \cr}

\myhalign{
first line & second column \cr
1& 2 \cr
}

\bye
```

[image]