# Using a loop in \halign's preamble

Tags: plain-tex

I've been trying to use a macro which abstracts the structure of an `\halign` object to a number of columns, as mentioned in my previous question
"[Can I use a macro in \halign's preamble?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495955/can-i-use-a-macro-in-haligns-preamble)." For that part of the problem, `\span` worked well, but I haven't been able to get an integrated solution working.

I tried to use this code:

```
\count1=4 \countdef\columns=1
\def\subpre{
  & ##
  \advance\columns by -1 \ifnum\columns>0 \span\subpre \fi
}
\def\preamb{
  ##
  \advance \columns by -1
  \the\columns
  \ifnum\columns>0 \span\subpre \fi
  \cr
}
\halign{\span\preamb
  first line \cr
  second line \cr
  third line \cr
}
\bye
```

to create an `\halign` which can be modified by changing the number which is assigned to `count1`, but this results in the error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\subpre ...by -1 \ifnum \columns >0 \span \subpre 
                                                  \fi 
\subpre ...by -1 \ifnum \columns >0 \span \subpre 
                                                  \fi 
\subpre ...by -1 \ifnum \columns >0 \span \subpre 
                                                  \fi 
\subpre ...by -1 \ifnum \columns >0 \span \subpre 
                                                  \fi 
\subpre ...by -1 \ifnum \columns >0 \span \subpre 
                                                  \fi 
\subpre ...by -1 \ifnum \columns >0 \span \subpre 
                                                  \fi 
...
l.13 \halign{\span\preamb
```

I think this is because the `\span\subpre` in `\subpre` automatically expands even if it's not supposed to be evaluated by the if statement, but I can't figure out how to expand it conditionally like in a "standard" recursive loop. What's the best way to conditionally expand the code within the if statement on line 4? I'm using Plain TeX.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `\preamb` has to be fully expandable. Can you use e-TeX features?

Comment: @HenriMenke I'd prefer to use just plain TeX because I'm trying to learn more about the underlying engine, but I'm just using this for a personal project, so I'd be able to. Which features would be necessary?

Comment: See for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428675/how-to-avoid-input-stack-overflow-during-recursion

Comment: all your columns are the same so you don't need a loop or count you could just use `\halign&#\cr` (or usually with some glue `\halign&#\hfill\cr` )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Henri Menke wrote in a comment, your preamble has to be expandable (and every token that should be expanded has to be preceded by `\span`). So how do we build a fully expandable loop only using plain TeX? We use `\romannumeral`. If `\count1` is some integer, then we can use `\the\count1 000` to get `1000*\count1`. This is expressed as a roman numeral by exactly `\count1` times the letter `m`. `\romannumeral` is expandable, so we can use this in our preamble. Then our macro is repeated, consuming one `m` at every iteration, until the `m`s run out:

```
\count1=4
\def\subpre#1{
  \span\if m#1
    & ##
    \span\expandafter
    \span\expandafter\subpre
  \fi
}
\def\gobble#1{}
\def\preamb{
  ##
  \span\expandafter
  \span\expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter\span\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\subpre
  \expandafter\gobble\romannumeral\the\count1 000x
  \cr
}
\halign{\span\preamb
  first& line&val&x \cr
}
\bye
```

To understand all the `\expandafter`s in `\preamb`, try to think as if you were TeX:
In `\preamb`, first we add `##` to the preamble. Then there is `\span`, so the next token is expanded. It is `\expandafter`, so we skip one token and expand the next, which (again) is `\expandafter`. This repeats 6 times, expanding the first, second, fourth, fifth, seventh and eighth `\expandafter` in `\preamb` until finally expanding `\romannumeral\the\count1 000x`. This expands to `\romannumeral4000x` and therefore `mmmmx`. Without the `\expandafter`s and `\romannumeral` expanded, we are left with the tokens

```
\span\expandafter
\span\expandafter\subpre\gobble mmmmx
```

Again, we have `\span`, so we expand this. The remaining `\expandafter`s end up expanding `\gobble` which gobbles the first `m`.
This is the equivalent to `\advance \columns by -1` in your original code. So what remains is

```
\span\subpre mmmx
```

which finally starts expanding `\subpre`.

On the other hand, it is often much easier to not restrict yourself to expandable constructs. Instead you can construct the preamble first (e.g.in a token list), and only insert the finished preamble into `\halign`: (based on David Carlisle's answer to your original question)

```
\newcount\columns
\newtoks\preambtoks
\def\myhalign{%
  \afterassignment\xmyhalign
  \columns=%
}
\def\xmyhalign{\afterassignment\xxmyhalign\let\tmp=}
\def\subpre{
  \preambtoks\expandafter{\the\preambtoks & ##}
  \advance\columns by -1 \ifnum\columns>0 \subpre \fi
}
\def\xxmyhalign{%
  \preambtoks{##}%
  \advance \columns by -1
  \ifnum\columns>0 \subpre \fi
  \halign\bgroup\span\the\preambtoks\cr
}

\myhalign3{
first line & second column \cr
1& 2&3 \cr
}
\bye
```

Comment: Very nice answer, +1! So, the `\afterassignment...\let\tmp=` in the last example is only there to gobble an opening brace, which wouldn't work with `\gobble` defined as `\def\gobble#1{}`, as that would swallow the whole braced group...

Comment: @frougon Right, the alternative would be to read the entire group as an argument and then using #1} in xxmyhalign, but that would fix the catcodes, messing up verbatim and similar stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The primitive `\span` in the context of a `\halign` preamble, performs a single expansion step.

You need some more sophisticated code if you want to allocate a variable number of columns.

Here I define `\preamb` to take as argument a column template (in the example, `\hfil#\hfil`); this template is repeated as many times as the current value of `\columns` (assumed to be positive).

The trick is to use `\span` to expand `` \romannumeral-`@ ``, that does recursive expansion until finding an unexpandable token.

The `\subpre` macro is called `\columns-1` times and each time the third argument contains the preamble-so-far augmented by a further column.

```
% syntactic sugar
\long\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\long\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}

% the code

\newcount\columns

\def\preamb#1{#1\span\romannumeral-`@\subpre\columns{#1}{}}

\def\subpre#1#2#3{%
  \ifnum\numexpr#1-1=0
    \expandafter\firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\secondoftwo
  \fi
  {#3\cr}%
  {\expandafter\subpre\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1}{#2}{#3&#2}}%
}

% the test

\tabskip=10pt
\columns=4
\halign{\span\preamb{\hfil#\hfil}%
  1&2&3&4\cr
  AAA&BB&CCCC&DDDD\cr
  u&v&w&x\cr
}

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: In my opinion an excellent user should not, at least when I am there, have zero scores when his answers are always by 110 e lode.